# What is this insect or lake dweller?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

Found on my deck. We live next to a lake. Don’t know if a bird dropped it?  Not sure whether to save it?  Has scalloped front legs and a point from the end of what I think are wings. Antennae, mouthparts. Back legs either deformed or partly missing because can’t propel forward, just rolling side to side   I put it in a pen to keep it safe for now.

Answer (score 7):

That is a mole cricket. Order Orthoptera, family, Gryllotalpidae https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_cricket
I'm not surprised you live by a lake. They burrow in sandy soil or sand, often right up to the water's edge. They can fly, but spend most of their time underground. You do not need to save it, as it will find its way back to its home if you just let it go. They are not pests. They don't bite, or spread disease.